# spring boot @Autowired a bean from another module

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ioc

My question is how can i add a package to my list of component to scan @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"io.swagger", "com.company.project", like add it here }),   but this package is in another module in my project,

here is the structure of my project :

springbootProject (maven project)/

```
  module1(mavenProject, com.company.module1)
       pom1.xml

  module2(mavenProject, com.company.module2)
       pom2.xml
```

pom.xml

in module 2 i have my main (@SpringbootAplication) where i want to @Autowired myRepository witch is in module 1

so how can i add the path

Comment: `ComponentScan` is not limited to the module it is used in. It scans the entire classpath during Spring context initialization

Answer (score 15):

Import ModuleB on ModuleA, and you'll be able to use it.

```
Project
|__ Module A (com.test.a)
|__ Module B (com.test.b)
```

In `pom.xml` on ModuleA, add:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>b</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you should be able to add:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.b"})
```

Comment: Yeah that's right what you say, but what i mean on my question, is that how the  main class (where there is the @SpringBootApplication ) will be able to scan the the module witch are

Comment: where would we put the @ComponentScan ?