# Springboot multimodule project

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, maven-3, multi-module

I'm trying to get a clean springboot maven multimodule project.
I'm using springboot 2.0.1.RELEASE

What I want to achieve is similar to this: [SpringBootMultipleMavenModules](https://github.com/dangeabunea/RomanianCoderExamples/tree/master/SpringBootMultipleMavenModules)

The problem I have is that I want to be able to inject my dependencies in any modules.

For example in this class: [DBSeeder.java](https://github.com/dangeabunea/RomanianCoderExamples/blob/master/SpringBootMultipleMavenModules/persistence/src/main/java/rc/persistence/DbSeeder.java) looks as follow:

```java
private HotelRepository hotelRepository;

public DbSeeder(HotelRepository hotelRepository){
    this.hotelRepository = hotelRepository;
}
..
```

I would like to use instead:

```java
@Autowired
private HotelRepository hotelRepository;
```

The Application class look as follow:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"rc"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"rc"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"rc"})
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Any idea that could link me to the solution would be welcome.

Comment: see my reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043699/spring-boot-autowired-a-bean-from-another-module/50044197#50044197

Comment: @MagdKudama That won't work unfortunately, already tried

Comment: what is it that would not work?

Comment: @MagdKudama Spring will complains: Field marriot in rc.persistence.DbSeeder required a bean of type 'rc.domain.Hotel' that could not be found.

Comment: I don't even see `rc.domain.Hotel` in your code. Is it included in the component scan (or entity, depends)? Is your DbSeeder class a bean? Try marking it as `@Component`

Comment: @MagdKudama Yes because I have changed the code that you see in the repo above. Its on my local computer. But trust me, I have add the maven deps and @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"rc"}). I  think I will add the code on my github. Will update shortly for the link.

Comment: Current version: https://github.com/IDCS1426/SpringBootMultipleMavenModules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, you cannot `Autowire` a `Hotel` bean, because it's not registered properly.

https://github.com/IDCS1426/SpringBootMultipleMavenModules/blob/master/domain/src/main/java/rc/domain/Hotel.java#L10

You need to add `@Component` there to be able to inject it in https://github.com/IDCS1426/SpringBootMultipleMavenModules/blob/master/persistence/src/main/java/rc/persistence/DbSeeder.java#L21

Also, the project will never compile, as you're adding a non-existing module: https://github.com/IDCS1426/SpringBootMultipleMavenModules/blob/master/pom.xml#L14. You need to remove that :).

Having said all of that, it's very weird to me the way you're trying to inject an `Entity` like that, but that's not part of this question.

By doing that, the code compiles just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I committed the app as it in the middle of changing the code. So the comment in github (won't inject). Apologizes if I committed an unstable version while asking for review. I will commit a proper a stable version later today.

Comment: Its a lab. I will resolve the entity through the repo

Answer (score 0):

The working solution is available [here](https://github.com/IDCS1426/SpringBootMultipleMavenModules). `@Component` was missing in the entity.
Obviously, beans shouldn't been injected like done here, but instantiated (eg `marriot = new Hotel("Marriot", 5, true);`) and persisted through the `save` method (or `saveAll` for a Collection)

The injection of entities for the sole purpose of initialisation is wrong and won't work:
The same instance will be reused for each Hotel.

```java
@Autowired
private Hotel marriot, ibis, goldenTulip;

@Override
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

    marriot.setName("Marriot");
    marriot.setClassification(5);
    marriot.setOpen(true);

    ibis.setName("Ibis");
    ibis.setClassification(3);
    ibis.setOpen(false);

    goldenTulip.setName("Golden Tulip");
    goldenTulip.setClassification(4);
    goldenTulip.setOpen(true);

    List<Hotel> hotels = new ArrayList<>();
    hotels.add(marriot);
    hotels.add(ibis);
    hotels.add(goldenTulip);

    this.hotelRepository.saveAll(hotels);
}
```

Will result in one entity persisted, as all the 3 hotels are the same instance. As such, http://localhost:8080/hotels will return:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Golden Tulip","classification":4,"open":true}]
```

While it with instantiation,

```java
@Override
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    marriot = new Hotel("Marriot", 5, true);
    ibis = new Hotel("Ibis", 3, false);
    goldenTulip = new Hotel("Golden Tulip", 4, true);

    List<Hotel> hotels = new ArrayList<>();
    hotels.add(marriot);
    hotels.add(ibis);
    hotels.add(goldenTulip);

    this.hotelRepository.saveAll(hotels);
}
```

it will return as it should the 3 entities:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Marriot","classification":5,"open":true},{"id":2,"name":"Ibis","classification":3,"open":false},{"id":3,"name":"Golden Tulip","classification":4,"open":true}]
```

That's exactly what I wanted to see here, but forgot adding `@Component` to the Entity class. Must not do that!

EDIT:
The reason for trying that was the use of a service layer:

```java
public interface NoteService {
    List<Note> loadAll();
}
```

```java
@Service
public class NoteServiceImpl implements NoteService {

  @Autowired
  private NoteRepository noteRepository;

  @Override
  public List<Note> loadAll() {
    return noteRepository.findAll();
  }
}
```

Which ended up failing at runtime, `Note` being not a managed bean.